# Read only specific rows of .parquet files matching criteria?

Tags: python, pyspark, pyarrow

I'm working against a filesystem filled with .parquet files. One of the columns, 'id', uniquely identifies a machine. I was able to use pyspark to open all .parquet files in a certain directory path, then create a set([]) of the values from the 'id' column. I'd like to open all other rows in all other files, where the 'id' matches one of the values in the previously calculated set.

I was able to do this via pyspark, but it's quite complex and requires me to instantiate a local spark server. I'm trying to find a way to do this via pyarrow, but it seems that it's read_pandas / read methods 'filters' argument can only filter on partition data, and not arbitrary column data.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for here? I can't open the entire dataset and then use Python to filter out rows where the 'id' doesn't match, because it doesn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 0.15.0, pyarrow doesn't have this feature, but we (in the Apache Arrow project) are actively working on this and hope to include it in the next major release.

Comment: Is there an issue tracking this?

Comment: There's not a single issue to watch. [This search](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20ARROW%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22)%20AND%20component%20in%20(%22C%2B%2B%22%2C%20Python)%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20dataset%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC%2C%20lastViewed%20DESC) should contain the relevant issues (and then some). Most of the current work on this new Dataset API is in C++; https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6341 is the first one for adding Python bindings.